# Personalizar colores de previous next en slider Bootstrap

Tags: html, css, bootstrap

Tengo un `carresul` con imágenes en mi sitio web. En dicho `carrusel` quiero cambiar/personalizar el **color** de las flechas (para destaque o se visualice correctamente sobre las imágenes -tienen fondo blanco y **previous/next** por defecto, incorporan el color blanco-).

En **Bootstrap**, he añadido `text-danger` para que las pueda repintar a rojas pero siguen en blanco.

¿Cómo podría resolverlo?

Código:

```html
<div id="carouselExampleIndicators" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel">
    <div class="carousel-inner">
        <div class="carousel-item active">
            <img src="img/img1.jpg" class="d-block w-100" alt="..." width="420px" height="350px">
        </div>
        <div class="carousel-item">
            <img src="img/img5.jpg" class="d-block w-100" alt="..." width="420px" height="350px">
        </div>
        <div class="carousel-item">
            <img src="img/img8.jpg" class="d-block w-100" alt="..." width="420px" height="350px">
        </a>
                                    
        </div>
    </div>
    <a class="carousel-control-prev" href="#carouselExampleControls" role="button" data-slide="prev" class="text-danger">
        <span class="carousel-control-prev-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
        <span class="sr-only">Previous</span>
    </a>
    <a class="carousel-control-next" href="#carouselExampleControls" role="button" data-slide="next" class="text-danger">
        <span class="carousel-control-next-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
        <span class="sr-only">Next</span>
    </a>
</div>
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Por cierto, lo del text-danger no está bien puesto. No puedes usar dos veces el atributo `class=` en un elemento, pues solo se lee el primero. Deberias poner todas las clases en un único atributo class= (aun así tampoco te habria funcionado, porque no es un texto, es una imagen)

Comment: @masterguru Me di cuenta al decirmelo que tenia varios class como atributo dentro de una sentencia, despiste mío. Y gracias por la aclaración. Seguiré el consejo que me diste con la propiedad "filter".

Comment: He actualizado mi respuesta con un snippet y un enlace a una tool que puede ayudarte a poner correctamente los valores del filter para un color específico.  Si mi respuesta soluciona tu pregunta puedes marcarla como aceptada para que la comunidad lo sepa y no quede pendiente eternamente.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Eso son iconos creados mediante svg/xml, y para modificarlos podrias probar con la propiedad filter:

```
.carousel-control-prev-icon, .carousel-control-next-icon {
  filter: invert(108%);
}
```

Eso te los resaltará mejor si el fondo es blanco. De todos modos tienes infinitas opciones con el atributo filter para modificar. Míralas en esta documentación: https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_filter.asp

Si necesitas un color específico puedes probar esta herramienta para generar los valores del filter:  https://codepen.io/sosuke/pen/Pjoqqp

Aquí te dejo un snippet de ejemplo para que lo ejecutes y veas que ahora salen más oscuros:

```css
.carousel-control-prev-icon, .carousel-control-next-icon {
  filter: invert(108%);
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.6.1/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-zCbKRCUGaJDkqS1kPbPd7TveP5iyJE0EjAuZQTgFLD2ylzuqKfdKlfG/eSrtxUkn" crossorigin="anonymous">

<div id="carouselExampleIndicators" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel">
  <div class="carousel-inner">
    <div class="carousel-item active">
      <img src="img/img1.jpg" class="d-block w-100" alt="..." width="420px" height="350px">
    </div>
    <div class="carousel-item">
      <img src="img/img5.jpg" class="d-block w-100" alt="..." width="420px" height="350px">
    </div>
    <div class="carousel-item">
      <img src="img/img8.jpg" class="d-block w-100" alt="..." width="420px" height="350px">
    </div>

  </div>
</div>
<a class="carousel-control-prev text-danger" href="#carouselExampleControls" role="button" data-slide="prev">
  <span class="carousel-control-prev-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
  <span class="sr-only">Previous</span>
</a>
<a class="carousel-control-next text-danger" href="#carouselExampleControls" role="button" data-slide="next">
  <span class="carousel-control-next-icon " aria-hidden="true"></span>
  <span class="sr-only">Next</span>
</a>
```